# Why doesn't make_unique work with a class which has an inline constructor?

Tags: c++11, smart-pointers

I have a well defined class like this,

```
class A
    {
    public:
        A();
        A(int a);
        A(const A& o);
        A(A&& o);
        ~A();
        A& operator=(const A& o);
        A& operator=(A&& o);
    private:
        int a = 0;
    };
```

At first, all the methods are in the .h file. Then I used the VS's refactoring function and moved all these methods to the .cpp file (It saved me a lot of labor.)
[image]

All the auto moved methods have a inline key word before them,

```
inline A::A()
    {
        cout << "A constructor\n";
    }
```

I know inline keyword, so I think it's OK.

Then I used this class in the third source file (.cpp file).

```
void test()
    {
        std::unique_ptr< A> a = std::make_unique<A>();

    }
```

When I compiled the project, It gave me an error LNK2019 happened in make_unique.

Then I deleted all the inline keyword, it worked.
I don't know why make_unique doesn't work when the class's consturctor is inline.

Comment: `inline` functions have to be defined (not just declared) in every source file they are used. The keyword is meant to be applied to functions defined in a header. It makes no sense to use it for functions defined in a .cpp file.

Comment: @NikitaKniazev, I have thought it's an unique_ptr problem. I just tested,it's a moving inline function to .cpp file problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have thought it's an unique_ptr problem. I just tested,it's a moving inline function to .cpp file problem.

With an inline constructor in .cpp file. Just creating a class A instance would fail.

```
A a;
```

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall
>   __AWellDefinedClass::A::A(void)" (??0A@__AWellDefinedClass@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl __pointerTest::test(void)"
>   (?test@__pointerTest@@YAXXZ)  ForTest D:\test\ForTest\ForTest\pointerTest.obj 1